# Why is m-fluorophenol less acidic than m-chlorophenol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, phenols

Why is **m-Fluorophenol** less acidic than all the other **m-Halophenols**, even though it has the most inductive effect

[image: peter sykes 6th edition data]

The data is from :
A guidebook to Mechanism in organic chemistry for the JEE, 6th edition, page no. 3.12 from the chapter, the strength of acids and bases

Comment: What are these values in the table?

Comment: What is the origin of the data?  For one, it is to provide an easy access of the data (for future readers of the question).  For two, how are the data obtained?  Isolated, i.e. gas phase acidities, or in a solvent?  The experimental recordings about *meta* chloro- or fluorophenol dissolved in DMSO for example, the Bordwell p$K_a$ table assigns both 15.8. [reference](https://organicchemistrydata.org/hansreich/resources/pka/#kaalcohol).

Comment: @Martin-マーチン, updated the book name, these are pka of the acids

Comment: @Buttonwood I think it's in aqueous medium like the most of data but not sure because they haven't mentioned anything specific

Comment: The trends are similar to Hammett sigma constants https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammett_equation  The halogens have opposing effects electron withdrawing by induction and electron donating by resonance. Fluorine by its size seems to be more effective in the electron donation than Cl, Br I.

Comment: @jimchmst but at meta position the donating effects cancel right?

Comment: Mesomeric effects are lower at the meta position.  Canonical forms are not the total answer. Check the differences between meta and para sigma constants  for the halogens, fluorine is interesting.